# In 2 Corinthians 10:4 what are the "weapons of our warfare" and "strongholds"?

Tags: symbolism, layers-of-meaning

> [2 Corinthians 10:4](https://biblehub.com/2_corinthians/10-4.htm) For the weapons of our warfare are not carnal,
>   but mighty through God to the pulling down of strong holds

What does this verse mean? What are our weapons? How are they mighty in God and what are the strongholds?

Comment: I watched an excellent video today that I think will give a gain to anyone wanting to understand this passage better: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTNJxFGmvA8

Answer (score 1):

The next verse give us a clue:-

> NWT  2 Corinthians 10:5  "For we are overturning reasonings and every lofty thing raised up against the knowledge of God, and we are bringing every thought into captivity to make it obedient to the Christ; ..."

To overturn false reasonings we need to use our Bible knowledge as noted beloow:-

> NWT  Ephesians 6:14-18 Spiritual Armor:-
>
> "Stand firm, therefore, with **the belt of truth fastened around your waist, wearing the breastplate of righteousness, 15 and having your feet shod in readiness to declare the good news of peace.** 16 Besides all of this, t**ake up the large shield of faith**, with which you will be able to extinguish all the wicked one’s burning arrows. 17 Also, **accept the helmet of salvation, and the sword of the spirit, that is, God’s word,** 18 while with every form of prayer and supplication you carry on prayer on every occasion in spirit. And to that end stay awake, constantly making supplication in behalf of all the holy ones."
>
> NWT 2 Timothy 2:3  "As a fine soldier of Christ Jesus, take your part in suffering adversity."

We have ti fight the good fight!

Strongholds:-

> NWT 2 Corinthians 10:4 "for overturning strongly entrenched things."

These are the bastions of falsehood built by false teachers who don't not use or teach the Bible correctly.  So Christians have the following to do:-

> NWT 2 Corinthians 10:5 "For we are overturning reasonings and every lofty thing raised up against the knowledge of God, and we are bringing every thought into captivity to make it obedient to the Christ; ..."

This is our spiritual warfare wherein we all the above weapons God supplies.

Comment: How is this done practically? "wearing", "having shod", "take up", "accept the helmet" etc?